# GLSL Shaders Attributes as ints

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm just learning OpenGL and I'm running into some issues.  I'm using OpenGL 3.0 and GLSL 1.2.

I have an array of matrices which I would like to selectively apply to different vertices. Instead of copying a matrix each time I want to indicate an index, I would instead like to pass in an integer as an index and use that integer to select the matrix I want.  However, when I try to compile my shader I get the following error:

```
ERROR: 0:5: 'attribute' : cannot be bool or int
```

I'd appreciate it if anybody could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Attributes can be ints, but you need to enable a newer version of GLSL to use it. Try adding this to the top of your shader:

```
#version 130
```

Version 130 corresponds to OpenGL 3.0

Comment: and for sending such attributes to the shader instead of glVertexAttrib* use its integer version - glVertexAttribI*

Comment: I'm using Mac OS X, which wont support 130.  Still, good to know.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Then you aren't using OpenGL 3.0... You're out of luck.

Comment: As of now, OSX supports GLSL versions up to 320 with core profile.